# How can I access the style defined by \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat elsewhere?

Tags: captions

#### Question

I have defined a certain font style for my captions and would like to use this in another part of my document. How can I access this style, so that I can reuse it?

*NB: I want to reproduce the style as a best practice for code re-use. I could just as well copy paste the code to that particular section of my document, but I think it could turn out to be an unwise decision later on.*

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionType{problem}[Problem]
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{problemlabel}{\color{red}▶~~%
    \sffamily#1~~#2}
\captionsetup[problem]{ labelformat=problemlabel }

\begin{document}

\captionof{problem}{This is a caption with the style ``problemlabel.''}

This text should somehow also by styled like a ``problemlabel.'' How can this be achieved?

\end{document}
```

---

#### Rationale

The reason for re-using the code is the following. I have defined a box that I use to set apart mathematical problems, which also get numbered and have a caption. In particular instances, however, I want to have such a box with a caption, but without a number in the caption, as in "Problem — *caption*" rather than "Problem 9 — *caption*". For this I would like to use a starred version of my environment.

The caption package provides the command \captionof*{}{}, however, this removes the entire label—not just the number. Therefore, I am trying to re-use the style of the original caption label in the design of the box, but now write down "Problem" myself.

The following code will make this clear:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{problembox}{smo}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={%
            \IfBooleanTF #1
            { \captionof*{problem}{#2} }%
            { \captionof{problem}{#2} }%
            \IfNoValueF{#3}{\label{#3}}%
        },
        style=boxstyle,
    ]
    \small
    }{%
    \end{mdframed}
}
```

*Instead of* the line `{ \captionof*{problem}{#2} }%`, I would like to have something in the likes of `{ {\captionlabelstyle Problem} #2 }`. That is why I need to access the style defined for the caption label.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, since you only format the *label* of the caption, yet the subsequent text doesn't seem to require a label, correct? ...so, using your example, you want the text to be `\color{red}` and `\sffamily`?

Comment: The `\caption` command is certainly not the right tool here. Perhaps you can describe more detailed what you are after.

Comment: @Werner, yes, that is indeed what I want to achieve. I just want to have the same font style as for the caption label elsewhere in my document. I am sorry to disappoint you, but it does make sense `:-)`. If you want to know the rationale (which should not be necessary), I have added it to the question for you.

@ThorstenDonig, I have also added the rationale for you. Hopefully this makes it clear why I need a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use captions at all for this task. I also believe that a star argument to an environment is very unusual. I'd rather define a starred variant instead (where the star is part of the environment name). Then I wouldn't define an optional argument for a label. It's easy to just add `\label` if you need it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,mdframed,xcolor,wasysym}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcommand*\problemformat{\sffamily\color{green!30!blue!70}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{problembox}{m}{%
  \refstepcounter{problem}%
  \mdframed[
    frametitle = {\RIGHTarrow\quad Problem \theproblem: #1} ,
    frametitlefont = \problemformat
  ]
    \problemformat\small
}{%
  \endmdframed
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{problembox*}{m}{%
  \mdframed[
    frametitle = {\RIGHTarrow\quad Problem: #1} ,
    frametitlefont = \problemformat
  ]
  \problemformat\small
}{%
  \endmdframed
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{problembox}{foo}\label{prb:foo}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{problembox}

See problem~\ref{prb:foo} \lipsum[4]

\begin{problembox*}{foo}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{problembox*}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your proposal. My rationale for using caption was that I can use some of its great features, for example generating a "List of Problems" (although that just sounds wrong, I know `:-)`). I am also neurotic about code duplication and try to things minimalistic, but I realize that might be just out of place here.

Comment: @Ingo it would be possible to add a list of problems to my proposal (although maybe not as convenient as with `caption`)